# Identify button by name using xpath

Tags: xpath

Can anyone advise how I can find this element by name using xpath?

```
<button style="position: relative; width: 69px;" type="button" class="x-btn-text " tabindex="0">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `//button[text()='Search']`

Answer (score 0):

`//button/text()` should return you "Search".